# API access to the /10m ("Thank you") web page?

Tags: feature-request, questions, statistics

https://stackoverflow.com/10m would be very interesting if you ask me: logging values periodically, and such.
However, [a recent issue I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304817/basic-ajax-request-gets-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-t/) showed that I can't just access it.

Since I've found no methods to gather out these numbers, is there any chance to query these numbers regularly anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this data easily by **scraping** or by using the **websocket** interface that Stack Exchange helpfully leaves available.

If you are making an application or webpage, just fetch [stackoverflow.com/10m](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) via your app-language's standard fetch/scrape utilities.  EG: [cURL](http://php.net/curl) if you are using PHP, etc.

For client side applications, make a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey/user script and use [GM_xmlhttpRequest()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest). It doesn't have the CORS restrictions.

For super-realtime, JS driven pages, the websocket is open cross-domain (at least until too many people abuse it).

See [an example using the websocket at jsBin](http://output.jsbin.com/fisilo/1).

Or run this code from your browser's console:

```js
var ws          = new WebSocket("ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/");
ws.onmessage    = function (messObj) {
    var payload = JSON.parse (messObj.data);
    var statName;

    switch (payload.action) {
        case "1-qcnt-feed":
            statName    = 'Questions';
        break;
        case "1-acnt-feed":
            statName    = 'Answers';
        break;
        case "1-evc-feed":
            statName    = 'Edits, Votes and Comments';
        break;
        default:
            statName    = 'Error! action == "' + payload.action + '".';
        break;
    }

    console.log (statName + ': ' + payload.data);
};
ws.onopen       = function () {
    ws.send ("1-evc-feed");
    ws.send ("1-acnt-feed");
    ws.send ("1-qcnt-feed");
};
window.ws = ws;  //debug:  Allows you to enter ws.close() from console.
```

Comment: "For super-realtime, JS driven pages, the websocket is open cross-domain (at least until too many people abuse it)." That is strange because I got an error when I attempted to make a standard `GET`˙request via jQuery.

Comment: Websockets and `GET` are quite a bit different.  And, jQuery is subject to CORS, the other approaches are not.  Did you try the code listed or visit the demo page?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know yet. I haven't tried the code yet, gonna reply if something happens.

Comment: It works, I could even adapt it to save values to variables. Thank you very much!